# Positioning input buttons and text in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would positioning form inputs(buttons, texts etc.) in html.

[image]

I would like to align left the buttons and pull down the text in the navbar. But i don't know how to do. I use bootstrap 3.

The codes:

```css
html,body{

     background-color: #F8F8F8;

    }

    .navbar{

     background-color: white;
     border: none;
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: 15px;
     margin-left: 100px;
     margin-right: 100px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <title>Moda Rüzgarı</title>
</head>
<body>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-white mr-auto" role="navigation">
     
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"><span class="sr-only"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="modaruzgari.png" height="75"></a>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu">
     
     <div class="input-group col-xs-5 col-lg-4">

      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Ara</button></span>
     
     </div>

     <span class="input-group-btn">
      
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;font-size: 13px;text-align: center;background: white;border: none;"><img src="girisyap.png" height="25">Giriş Yap</button>

     <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;font-size: 13px;text-align: center;background: white;border: none;"><img src="sepetim.png" height="25">Sepetim</button>

     </span>

    </div>

    </div>
```

open full page if you open snippet please.

I need your help.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Pleaso post your code so we may help you.

Comment: @jalazbe i edited the question

Comment: What is the problem you are facing right now? looking at the code snippet it seems that the icons are in the left and the text is below the icons. Isn't that?

Comment: The code doesn't look complete. Can you post the entire Navbar?

Comment: @Themes.guide i edited the code. Please open full page snippet.

Comment: @CalvinNunes iedited the code. Please look the snippet full page.

Comment: Can you perhaps post a jsfiddle with the complete code? Or a link to a live website? I tried looking into this, but there's too many things missing to give an answer...

Comment: try using `form.inline` class in the button div to use form elements inside the navigation bar.
To align to the left put each button inside a row class div: `<div class="row">`.
and then al use `pull-left` in the btn div class.